# Odd file does not exist error

Tags: c#, android, file, xamarin

I'm running into an error that I can't catch and it should not be there.

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists (PathToMyFile)) 
{
    try{
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(PathToMyFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
        br.Close();
        fs.Close();
        myFile =Convert.ToBase64String  (bytes) ;
        }
    catch{}
    }
```

For some reason , sometimes I get a exception error that the file does not exist when It most definitely is there. The very first "If statement" even says it is there yet when trying to open the file I sometimes get a massive app crash that the catch does not "catch" .

Like I said, it's a random error, most of the time the code is perfect but the odd occasion seems to throw an error that the app stops working .

Comment: Could you tell us what is the error? use `catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
        }` and read the error

Comment: can't seem to replicate it right now but the error is a file does not exist , think its a Java lang error if not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to make sure you close the file\stream

So you can call fs.Close() or using

```
if (File.Exists(pathToMyFile))
{
   try
   {
      using (var fs = new FileStream(pathToMyFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
         BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
         Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32) fs.Length);
         br.Close();
         fs.Close();
         myFile = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
      }
   }
   catch
   {
      // Log exception
   }
}
```

Second, if you need to read the file as string, simply use

```
if (File.Exists(pathToMyFile))
{
   try
   {
      myFile = File.ReadAllText(pathToMyFile);
   }
   catch
   {
      // Log exception              
   }
}
```